# UIScrollView Inside UIView set as tableHeaderView not scrolling

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm running into an issue where I have a uiview at the bottom, where I need to add a few labels that I want to remain static. Then I'm adding a scrollview on top of the uiview with some scrollable content. And finally I'm setting the original uiview as the table headerView. And the scrollView is not scrolling despite correct contentSize.

```
UIView *header=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100*objects.count, 150)];
        [header setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    //set up scroll view
    UIScrollView *scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 100*objects.count, 110)];
    scrollView.delegate=self;
    scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(100*objects.count, scrollView.frame.size.height);
    [scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];

    [header addSubview:scrollView];

    [scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:YES];
    [self.tableView setTableHeaderView:header];

    //add stuff to scroll view
```

However when I set just the scrollView as the tableHeaderView, the scrolling works perfectly

```
    [self.tableView setTableHeaderView:scrollView];
```

Can anyone suggest how I can set the original botton uiview as the header view and have the scrollView still work?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot so we can get better idea?

Comment: nothing really to see except that the scroll view is not scrolling

Comment: may be a boundary issue.

Answer (score 1):

solution was to use scrollViewDidScroll delegate method of the scroll view and adjust the content offset by the amount scrolled. kind of hacky, still don't know why this scrollview issue was happening, but it worked for now.

looks like

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

    [self.featuredLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(5+scrollView.contentOffset.x, 5, self.view.frame.size.width, 18)];
    [self.recentLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(5+scrollView.contentOffset.x, 100, self.view.frame.size.width, 18)];

}
```

can't find the so post that mentioned it